# Как добавить View к CollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Есть необходимость добавить View на CollectionViewController, чтобы View не был растянут на весь экран, а был внизу экрана. При попытке добавить View на CollectionViewController происходит следующее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Черный цвет - View, синий - CollectionCell. Мне нужно чтобы View расположился внизу экрана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае нельзя использовать UICollectionViewController (или UITableViewController, они практически не отличаются).

Вместо этого создайте обычный UIViewController и на него добавьте UICollectionView и UIView. Через autolayout проставьте констрейнты для обоих контролов, скорее всего у вас получится что-то вроде: CollectionView 0 до верха, лева, права и UIView, UIView 0 до низа, лева, права и высота = X. (т.е view у вас будет фиксированной высоты и collectionView растягивается в зависимости от девайса)

После этого наследуете контроллер от протоколов, нужных для реализации collectionView и ставите

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

во `viewDidLoad()`

Дальше работаете, как обычно.

Абсолютно аналогично решается эта задача для UiTableView. Запомните железное правило: если вам требуется помимо таблицы/collectionView отобразить на странице еще что-то, то UITableViewController/UICollectionViewController использовать нельзя.